# Подключение к базе данных Progress

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Доброе утро!

У нас есть база данных на базе Progress. В источниках данных я прописал подключение к БД, обозвал его server. В Delphi добавил компонент ADOConnection1, в поле прописал подключение

```
(Provider=MSDASQL.1; Password=odbc; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=odbc; Mode=Read; Extended Properties="DSN=server; UID=ODBC; PWD=***; HOST=192.168.3.157; PORT=5005; DB=ub")`
```

в поле connected ставим true.

Добавил еще один компонент ADOTable, в поле Connection поставил ADOConnection1, в поле TableName проставил нужную таблицу, в поле Active ставлю True и программа выдает сообщение об ошибке

> `[Data Direct][ODBC Progress driver][Progress]Table/View/Synonym not found (7519)`

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте перед именем таблицы в свойстве TableName добавить `PUB.`.

Например: `PUB.MY_TABLE`

Comment: Да спасибо большое!
Заработало!!!!!

Comment: там галочка есть слева от ответа, чтобы принять